# Scaler values vs array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Consider following two collections and followed note. Which one do you think is more appropriate ?

```
// #1
{x:'a'}
{x:'b'}
{x:'c'}
{x:['d','e']}
{x:'f'}
```

.

```
//#2
{x:['a']}
{x:['b']}
{x:['c']}
{x:['d','e']}
{x:['f']}
```

some facts:

- field `x` have usually only one value (95%) and some times more (5%).
- Mongodb behaves with {x:['a']} like {x:'a'} while querying.
- MongoVUE shows scaler values in #1 directly and shows `Array[0]` for #2.
- Using #1, when you want append a new value you have to cast data types
- #1 May be a little faster in some CRUD operation (?)

Comment: I'd use arrays always. Code is simpler this way. Simpler code - less chance for bugs.

Comment: I would also say #1, for the sake of simplicity and uniformity.

Answer (score 1):

To amplify @ZaidMasud's point I recommend staying with sclars or arrays and not mix both.  If you have unavoidable reasons for having both (legacy data, say) then I recommend that you get very familiar with how Mongo queries work with arrays; it is not intuitive at first glance.  See for example [this puzzler](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/12/27/mongodb-puzzlers-1/).

Answer (score 0):

From a schema design perspective, even though MongoDB allows you to store different data types for a key value pair, it's not necessarily a good idea to do so. If there is no compelling reason to use different data types, it's often best to use the same datatype for a given key/value pair.

So given that reasoning, I would prefer #2. Application code will generally be simpler in this case. Additionally, if you ever need to use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/), you will find it useful to have uniform types.